Why first _ is not counted as positional argument?
Lets take a look at my example
bash -c 'echo $#' _ x

gives
1

bash -c 'echo $#' _ x _ y

gives
3

why?

looks like a duplicate of Why $0 is not a positional parameter?

Related: https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/find/#shell
